# Close Electron frameless window not working

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm building an app using electron 1.0 and unfortunately everywhere I look for guides and tutorials with it, no one uses electron 1 because it's so new.

I am trying to close a frameless window through the click of a button I made.  I know the button works because I have check to make sure it can do simple things (i.e. change some text or whatever) but that's only when I use internal javascript but I am trying to use external javascript. When I use external the function never gets called...

```
    const {remote} = require('electron');
    const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote;

    document.getElementById("close-button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
         var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
         window.close();
    });
```

That is my javascript file. I also know I am linking the file properly because I can use document.write() and it works.

What am I doing wrong here?

any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Edit: Added remote line.

Although there is another reason why my event handler isn't working for my button.  This question is closed and the answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you omitted the relevant import from the snippet you posted, but assuming you haven't `remote` will be undefined when you call `remote.getCurrentWindow()`. If you add `const { remote } = require('electron');` to the top of your snippet I think your click handler will work as expected.

Comment: I did forget to use that line, but I added it and still no luck. Nothing happens on click.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @ClaytonPerroni If that didn't work then why is this answer selected as correct? If it did not solve the question please do not mark it as the answer. If you found a different solution please create an answer and mark that as correct so that others can benefit.

Comment: @JimmyBoh Someone already commented this but I guess they rage deleted their comments. This did solve my problem. There was an issue as to how I was calling the function as an external JS file. I used a workaround where I used a local js function to call an external js function and it worked. This is the correct solution.

Comment: Well that's great then. Thank you very much for clarifying!