# Electron BrowserWindow.unmaximize() Custom Window frame dont work

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a problem using
     BrowserWindow.unmaximize
 in electron and BrowserWindow.isMaximized
because im making a application with a custom window frame this is a big problem that its not working

Here is my Code::

```
const $ = require('jquery');
var remote = require('electron').remote; 


var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();

$('#actionBarWindowMin').click(function(e){
  win.minimize();
});

$('#actionBarWindowClose').click(function(e){
  win.close();
});

$('#actionBarWindowMax').click(function(e) {

//Problem is here


  if(win.isMaximized()){
      win.unmaximize();
  }else{
      win.maximize();
  }

// -------------    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37506671/6786876) answer on nearly the same problem, it might do the trick if you use

`const {remote} = require('electron');`

I've had the same issue with `var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;`. Enclosing `ipcMain` with curly brackets and changing the var to const did the trick.